# Why does this javascript stop working on refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var highestBox = 0;
  $('#clubs .bcbox').each(function () {
    if ($(this).height() > highestBox) {
      highestBox = $(this).height();
    }
  });
  $('#clubs .bcbox').height(highestBox);
});
```

And the HTML is:

```
<div id="clubs">
  <div class="bcbox">short box</div>
  <div class="bcbox">A box with a lot of content, so that the heights aren't the same.</div>
</div>
```

Each .bcbox is half the width of #clubs, however height varies based on content. 
It works in most browsers, however in Chrome if I refresh the page the javascript doesn't work.

Comment: What does the Chrome console say?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome. Each div gets the height set to 20px.

Comment: Working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jr191xn8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your script might be getting cached, try clearing your cache between refreshes.